# How does a woman prepare her body before becoming pregnant?

Tags: health, food, activities, pregnancy

My husband and I are planning on conceiving a child in the next year and were wondering what types of things women should do to prepare their bodies for pregnancy?

We are wondering about vitamins, foods, activities, books, and any other resources that could help.  I am 31 years old, in average shape, and am in a secure job.

Comment: Do you want to have better chances of conceiving a child? If so, Torben suggests reading a simiar question's answers. Otherwise, consider extending the question so that we can understand exactly what you mean.